# Extract body of commit message from git-show output

Tags: git

## Context

Let's suppose I have the following commit:

```
PS C:\temp\2021-05-06> git show eb60d3426333b6b6ba5cf34b8de36377b90c5868

commit eb60d3426333b6b6ba5cf34b8de36377b90c5868 (HEAD -> master)
Author: dharmatech <dharmatech@xyz.com>
Date:   Thu May 6 10:34:03 2021 -0700

    abc

    bcd
    cde
    def

diff --git a/bcd b/bcd
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..a034a61
Binary files /dev/null and b/bcd differ
```

## The issue

I'd like to extract the commit message body (without the subject).

The following bit of PowerShell code does the trick:

```
$id = 'eb60d3426333b6b6ba5cf34b8de36377b90c5868'

$elts = git show $id | Select-Object -Skip 5

foreach ($elt in $elts)
{
    if ($elt -match '^diff --git a')
    {
        break
    }

    $elt
}
```

It outputs:

```
bcd
cde
def
```

## Question

Is there a more straightforward way to perform the above that's perhaps built-in to the git tools?

If there isn't, would there be a better approach to parsing out the body lines?

Comment: `git log` has `--format` directives; there are about 100 of them. Several of them aim at producing just what you want, including `%b`, which is the closest to what you want.

Comment: Thanks @torek! With your suggestion to look into `%b`, I was able to find a way to get it done with `git show` (same directive). I posted what worked for me below. Quite straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ git log abcdef0 --format=%b
<BODY>
```

From [`man 1 git-log`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/extra/git/git-log.1.en):

> `--pretty[=<format>], --format=<format>` Pretty-print the contents of the
> commit logs in a given format, where `<format>` can be one of `oneline`,
> `short`, `medium`, `full`, `fuller`, `reference`, `email`, `raw`,
> `format:<string>` and `tformat:<string>`. When `<format>` is none of the
> above, and has `%placeholder` in it, it acts as if
> `--pretty=tformat:<format>` were given.
>
> See the "PRETTY FORMATS" section for some additional details for each format.
> When `=<format>` part is omitted, it defaults to `medium`.

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I ended up using:

```
PS C:\temp\2021-05-06> git show --no-patch 'eb60d3426333b6b6ba5cf34b8de36377b90c5868' --format='%b'

bcd
cde
def
```

The key to removing the diff portion was `--no-patch`.